# Run jest and Return TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am now testing the behavior when the button is pressed in Jest and it returns the following error

```bash
$ npm run test                                                             

> Solana-Wallet@0.1.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/index.test.js

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')

      32 |
      33 |     user.click(screen.getByText("Generate Wallet"));
    > 34 |     const words = mnemonicElement.textContent.split(" ");
         |                                   ^
      35 |     expect(words.length).toBe(12);
      36 |   });
      37 |

      at Object.textContent (__tests__/index.test.js:34:35)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 4 todo, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.951 s
```

**[Test Code]**

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Home from "../pages/index";
import { unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
  // setup a DOM element as a render target
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  // cleanup on exiting
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});

describe('Home', () => {
  it("generates a mnemonic phrase when the button is clicked", () => {
    act(() => {
      render(<Home />, container);
    });

    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const mnemonicElement = screen.queryByTestId("mnemonic-display");

    user.click(screen.getByText("Generate Wallet"));
    const words = mnemonicElement.textContent.split(" ");
    expect(words.length).toBe(12);
  });
});
```

What I want to test is the functionality of the `Generate Wallet` button. When this button is pressed, the handler `generateWallet` function is executed and the mnemonic phrase (12 words) generated in it is displayed on the browser.
I want to get the mnemonic phrase displayed in the browser in our test.

**[pages/index.js]**

```js
import HeadComponent from "../components/Head";
import {
  Keypair,
  Connection,
  clusterApiUrl,
  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  SystemProgram,
  PublicKey,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import * as Bip39 from "bip39";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [mnemonic, setMnemonic] = useState(null);
  const [account, setAccount] = useState(null);

  const generateWallet = () => {
    const generatedMnemonic = Bip39.generateMnemonic();
    setMnemonic(generatedMnemonic);
    console.log("generatedMnemonic", generatedMnemonic);

    const seed = Bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(generatedMnemonic).slice(0, 32);
    console.log("seed", seed);

    const newAccount = Keypair.fromSeed(seed);
    console.log("newAccount", newAccount.publicKey.toString());

    setAccount(newAccount);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button
          className="p-2 my-6 text-white bg-indigo-500 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer"
          onClick={generateWallet}
        >
          Generate Wallet
        </button>
        {mnemonic && (
          <>
            <div className="mt-1 p-4 border border-gray-300 bg-gray-200" data-testid="mnemonic-display">
              {mnemonic}
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was necessary to use the [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) function to wait an arbitrary amount of time until the expected value could be obtained.

By modifying the test code as follows, the test passed successfully.

```js
  it("generates a mnemonic phrase when the button is clicked", async () => {
    act(() => {
      render(<Home />, container);
    });

    const user = userEvent.setup();

    user.click(screen.getByText("generateWallet"));
    // Use waitFor
    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(screen.queryByTestId("mnemonic-display")).not.toBeNull());

    const mnemonicElement = screen.queryByTestId("mnemonic-display");

    const words = mnemonicElement.textContent.split(" ");
    expect(words.length).toBe(12);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `mnemonic` div isn't rendered initially. You should be clicking the generate wallet button, which will populate `mnemonic` state value, which will then cause the div with `data-testid="mnemonic-display"` to be rendered, and THEN do `const mnemonicElement = screen.queryByTestId("mnemonic-display");`. By declaring the mnemonic variable in the test *before* you click the button, it will be undefined, and you don't reassign it after the button click. Basically, swap the mnemonic and click lines so it's like this:

```
    // First click the button, so mnemonic state value is populated and the div will be rendered
    user.click(screen.getByText("Generate Wallet"));

    // THEN try to query the element, which should be rendered now
    const mnemonicElement = screen.queryByTestId("mnemonic-display");

    // Now you can do whatever with the element
    const words = mnemonicElement.textContent.split(" ");
```

Since it's a state change and state changes are async I don't know if you have to `await` anything in the test, but that's why it's undefined

Comment: Thank you for response!

As you pointed out, I moved the assignment to mnemonicElement back, but I get the same error.

I am just starting to learn jest and the test code was created based on [this tutorial](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/unit-testing-of-react-apps-using-jest)